# IRS retrieving error response file

Tags: java, soap, mtom, irs

How can I program in java to get the attachment?
I finally got this program to send mtom, and receive a status update.  Part of that soap message from the IRS coming back has attachment with the list of errors in the submitted file.  I have been searching the net trying to find out how to download the attachment from the response. I get the response soap message and I then try to do this with it:

```
private void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
        smc.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        out.println("\nOutbound message:");
    } else {
        out.println("\nInbound message:");
    }

    SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
    try {ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(bout);
    String outfpn =p.getPath()+File.separator+"ErrorReport_"+getRecieptID()+icec+".xml";
    icec++;
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outfpn);
    message.writeTo(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        out.println("");   // just to add a newline
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Exception in handler: " + e);
    }
}


Soap message response:

------=_Part_3_10783799.1471300737900
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns5:ACABusinessHeader xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common"     xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0"     xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-    utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"     xmlns:ns5="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest"     xmlns:ns6="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader"     xmlns:ns7="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-    secext-1.0.xsd" ns3:Id="id-962DC498C98A4E58A8DF4AA1861A4E81">
            <ns2:UniqueTransmissionId>e6b9f6c9-01df-4003-993a-    47b15fc2c236:SYS12:::T</ns2:UniqueTransmissionId>
            <Timestamp>2016-08-15T22:37:50Z</Timestamp>
        </ns5:ACABusinessHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns5:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailResponse     xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common"     xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0"     xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-    utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"     xmlns:ns5="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest"     xmlns:ns6="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader"     xmlns:ns7="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-    secext-1.0.xsd">
            <ns2:ACABulkRequestTransmitterResponse>
                    <ns2:TransmissionStatusCd>Rejected</ns2:TransmissionStatusCd>
                <ReceiptId>1095B-16-0</ReceiptId>
            </ns2:ACABulkRequestTransmitterResponse>
            <ns2:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsRespGrpDtl>
                <BulkExchangeFile>
                    <xop:Include     xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:5aadb03f-8cb4-44bb-    8657-3f63b545904d-374@urn%3Aus%3Agov%3Atreasury%3Airs%3Acommon"/>
                </BulkExchangeFile>
            </ns2:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsRespGrpDtl>
        </ns5:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
------=_Part_3_10783799.1471300737900
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: attachment;name="respMTOM"
Content-ID: <5aadb03f-8cb4-44bb-8657-3f63b545904d-    374@urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


------=_Part_3_10783799.1471300737900--
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late to the party, and my solution is in `C#` whereas your solution is in `java`.  However, maybe I can explain how I'm doing this, and you could apply something similar to your solution, if you haven't already.

**Reading/Processing the Response**

1. Read the first line of the response and assign it to a MimeBoundary property.  This first line is the `UUID` as well as the `MimeBoundary` of the response object.
2. Concatenate the `MimeBoundary` with the characters for a control feed/line break (`\r\n`), and the rest of the response object by using the `ReadToEnd()` method.  Read this concatenated string into a string property, `ResponseString`.
3. Create a variable (`match`) to store the return of the `Regex.Match()` method and use a pattern to find the `ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailResponse` node within the `ResponseString`.
4. Call a `Deserializer<T>` method which will use the `XmlSerializer` to convert the `match` variable into a `ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailResponseType` object.  Assign this to a property `StatusDetailResponse`.
5. Use the `StatusDetailResponse` property to find the value of the `TransmissionStatus`.  If the TransmissionStatus is equal to "AcceptedwithErrors", "PartiallyAccepted" or "Rejected", an Error Attachment will be present in the Response.

**Reading/Processing the Attachment**

1. Find the index of the Declaration XML (`DeclarationIndex`) within the `ResponseString`.  If the index is -1, no attachment is found.  According to the IRS, this can happen, when this happens, update the `ContactPersonLastName` field and re-send the Transmission as a `Replacement`.  If it is greater than -1, there should be an attachment.
2. Find the entire string of the attachment by retrieving a `Substring` of the `ResponseString` starting with the `DeclarationIndex` and ending with the `LastIndexOf` the `MimeBoundry` minus the `DeclarationIndex`.  Assign this string to an `AttachmentXML` variable.
3. I created a class for the `SubmissionDetailResponse` which was created by taking a sample of the XML output for the `Error Attachment` and creating a class out of it in `.NET`.  `Deserialize` the `AttachmentXML` into this `SubmissionDetailResponse` class.
4. Process the data from the `SubmissionDetailResponse` into the database for error review.